# TRIAC confusion

Tags: power-electronics, opto-isolator, switching, triac, snubber

First for some **quick background**:
You might be aware of my other threads in which I pose a problem with **micro-controller to WiFi-command an existing coffee machine** which had (as happens with a lot of home appliances) NON-isolated Power Supply.

I've already gathered both the components and, more or less, the basic understanding for this to finally work.

I got a couple **MOC3041 opto-triacs** and a little PCB mounted Meanwell IRM-10-5 2A @ 5V **isolated PS** to try and finish my "project".

This is a **very nice "project"** since it is providing the coffee machine both with a programmable "algorithm" for coffee making uC (ATTiny85) AND a ESP01 little module for WiFi activation, not to mention two USB backports to offline (re)programming of BOTH uC's and TADA!!! even a nice D-sub15 back port for full debugging of all the digital signals going on (even of the Gauge temp!)

But I digress: my main question right now when I need to proceed to final mountage is very simple:

**MAIN QUESTION:**
Can **HOT and NEUTRAL get interchanged** in the following picture WHEN THE **LOAD IS NOT AS DEPICTED** BUT ON THE "UPPER LINE" ?

[image: TRIAC CONTROL WITH MOC3041 OPTOCOUPLER]

(source: MOC3041 opto-triac coupler datasheet)

(i.e. imagine LOAD not down there but put between the HOT and the 360R, and THEN imagine we interchange HOT and NEUTRAL after that). Would it work? Would it blow my TRIAC?

A couple other **related questions**:

2. For the HEATER control a ST T1235T-8G snubberless TRIAC is used, so I wouldn't maybe need the **snubber network** depicted right? For the case of the fewer current-capable ACST controlling the PUMP element, though, it would be needed since it's an Inductive loads by all means. Then, what would be your best recommendations both for the 39R **wattage** AND the **nature or physical type** of the 0,01uF capacitor we see?  And, even in this ACST case, could it be dealt without the snubber components, with which risks if any?
3. In most schemas out there I found that they use a (conveniently calculated) R in the gate activation line. Here we see some 330R, yes, but it's somehow connected in another way. How come this 330R is not directly **ON** the gate wire?  (to me it seems most similar to the typical use of a resistor between B and E of a switching BJT in order to make sure it is *truly* "OFF" when it *should* be OFF...)

And finally:

4. The situation is of course (learned the hard way) that of **ISOLATED POWER SUPPLY case**. If it were NON-ISOLATED then you'd have to consider whether it's "negative power supply" or "positive" cases in regards to whether you'd have the VSS or the VCC of the DC control logic tied to **REFERENCE** (which I assume is always taken to be A1 terminal on the TRIAC, or COM for ACST.) Am I right in this?

**USEFUL REFERENCE (MAYBE):**
"[TRIAC Tutorial](https://www.daycounter.com/LabBook/TRIAC-Tutorial.phtml)" I found out there, says this literally  (but **seems CONTRADICTORY** to the given Figure! what am I missing?)

> TRIACs look deceptively simple to use, however, a few design guidelines need to be followed.
>
> At first glance you would think that since a TRIAC is controlling AC, it's two terminals M1 an M2 would be interchangeable. This isn't the case, if you swap M1 and M2 the TRIAC will not work. The gate drive must be referenced to M1. The schematic symbol for the TRIAC always has the gate drawn by M1, to show the asymmetry of the device.
>
> The load should always be placed on M2 and not M1. This is important because this will cause the AC voltage to appear across the gate resistor, and will cause it to overheat and even melt. Yep, you guessed it - I've made this mistake.

This is one of my "fears" so to speak. In the case of ISOLATED powering for the control (uC) logic, DOES it really matter either to interchange HOT and NEUTRAL?  And to interchange A1 and A2?  I know where the load is NOT supposed to be inserted (my schema is most similar to the picture I gave in the beginning, BUT only I need HOT-NEUTRAL reversed, and besides with the LOAD on "top" so to speak.)

Many thanks for all your advice and contributions!!!

Comment: Cross posted here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/38359/10902

Comment: thanks for the remark, it’s true, I originally posted that version and then forgot to erase it after posting a more complete version in this forum which seemed most apropriate.I have removed the other post since.

Comment: No, you have not removed the other post - it is still there.

Comment: Sorry again, I noticed the right post was here, and I had it deleted the other way round and after that I didn't fix things. Newbie failure I guess :)   Now it IS deleted.

Comment: PARTIALLY SOLVED:

Answer (score -1):

(PARTIAL SOLUTION SO FAR):
I've learnt by other sources (documentation, some forums of electrical engineer's fame with users which reported similar doubts). Since this is for controlling AC, then it's somehow indifferent whether you interchange LIVE and NEUTRAL, or even whether you "insert" the load in the path to one mains wire or the other.

BUT!! This said, I must ADVISE by the way to NEVER connect the LOAD "in the middle" between the node which connects LIVE (or NEUTRAL) to your MOC30xxx's PIN 6 (and whether you use a limiting resistor between LIVE and p.6 or not --sometimes the only limiting resistor you have is connected ON the GATE wire).

That is, the LIVE (or NEUTRAL) must connect VIA THE LOAD to the TRIAC's T2 terminal: from that connection you then derive another wire (or an appropriate R) between it and MOC's pin 6. Either this, or you connect the LOAD in the "return" path (i.e. between TRIAC's T1 terminal and the other wire from the mains). BUT NEVER LET THE LOAD SHARE THE SAME PATH WITH THE TRIAC BETWEEN its pin T2 and the mains wire which goes to MOC's pin 6, since this would either burn your TRIAC or your resistor (if it's e.g. only 1/4 or 1/2 Watt on the limit of calculations) AND your MOC along with it (as it happened to me in one of my tests).

Comment: your statement is little confusing for me, can you please share some schematic picture so that it will be more clear, actually I was stuck in the same point. Thanks.